# react-bootstrap not importing properly

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to put together a trivial example of react-bootstrap to see it in action, but I'm not getting any components to render properly. For example,

Here is a trivial component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {ButtonToolbar, DropdownButton, MenuItem} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>

      <ButtonToolbar>
        <DropdownButton bsSize="large" title="Large button" id="dropdown-size-large">
          <MenuItem eventKey="1">Action</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem eventKey="2">Another action</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem eventKey="3">Something else here</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem divider />
          <MenuItem eventKey="4">Separated link</MenuItem>
        </DropdownButton>
      </ButtonToolbar>
    </div>
  }
});
```

here is the index.html where i'm loading in the scripts

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700"></link>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.3/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.28.1/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've confirmed ButtonToolbar, DropdownButton, and MenuItem are getting imported in, and the scripts are loading ok, but the component is just plain html, not bootstrap style. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly [add the bootstrap CSS](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html#setup) to your project. The CSS style is not included with the react bootstrap components.

Check [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) for options on how to include it in your project.

One option is to install the `bootstrap` package

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

and link to the stylesheet in your HTML file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
```

Comment: You can also use css-loader,style-loader and less-loader and less. Then refer in the following way in component file. require('!style!css!less!bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less');